# How to avoid to repeat a variable

Tags: javascript, while-loop

Hi I'm new to javascript and was wondering if the community could help me in re-writing more logically the following snippet:

```
var userAnswer = prompt("Are we there yet?") 

while ((userAnswer != "yes" && userAnswer != "yeah") && (userAnswer.indexOf("yes") === -1)) {

var userAnswer = prompt ("Are we there yet?")

}

alert ("Yuppie we made it!")
```

the part that I think could be improved is in the while loop when I have to repet the entire string of `var userAnswer = prompt....`
there must be a dry way of doing it. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while

Comment: (I formatted the code in your question for you, please do that yourself in the future. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to run ask for a value at least once you could use `do-while` instead. You could define variable within the do block, it still will be hoisted.

```js
do {
  var userAnswer = prompt("Are we there yet?")
} while ((userAnswer != "yes" && userAnswer != "yeah") && (userAnswer.indexOf("yes") === -1))

alert("Yuppie we made it!")
```

PS. I kept the condition assuming it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `prompt` to enter free text use `confirm` that will return true or false:

```js
while (!confirm("Are we there yet?"));
alert("Yuppie we made it!")
```

Answer (score 0):

A way of doing it without using a while loop.

```
var answer = prompt ("Are we there yet?", "YES or NO")
answer != "yes" ? prompt ("Are we there yet?", "YES or NO"): alert("We made it !!");
```